# What's wrong? Defining a JavaScript namespace via string

Tags: javascript, namespaces

I use the following code to define a new namespace called com.foo

```
function extendNamespace(ns, ns_string) {
    var parts = ns_string.split('.');
    var parent = ns;

    for (var i = 0; i < parts.length; i++) {
        //create a property if it doesnt exist
        if (typeof parent[parts[i]] == 'undefined') {
            parent[parts[i]] = {};
        }
        parent = parent[parts[i]];
    }
    return ns;
}

var com = {};
extendNamespace(com, "com.foo");

console.log(com); // OK (even has an object called "foo"!!)
console.log(com.foo); // Undefined ???
```

The first call of `console.log(com)` clearly shows me in console that a new object "com" has been created which has an object called "foo".

So far, so good.

The second call `console.log(com.foo);` though returns me "undefined".

What gives?

Comment: If you have a closer look, you'll that the structure is `com.com.foo`. You pass `com` into the function and the string `'com.foo'` which adds the nested properties `com` and `com.foo` to the object you pass in.

Comment: @Felix If you had just posted this as the answer you'd have 40 points already. The 3 comment votes + my vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The first call of console.log(com) clearly shows me in console that a new object "com" has been created which has an object called "foo".

No. It has a property called `com`, the value of which is an object with a property called `foo`.

You are extending `com` with `com.foo` when you only want to extend it with `foo`.

Comment: You're right! So the correct call would be `extendNamespace(com, "foo");`